# How do I extract information from inner parameters in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In most of programming languages that support mutable variables, one can easily implement something like this *Java* example:

```java
interface Accepter<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}

<T> T getFromDoubleAccepter(Accepter<Accepter<T>> acc){
    final List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
    acc.accept(new Accepter<T>(){

        @Override
        public void accept(T t) {
            l.add(t);
        }

    });
    return l.get(0); //Not being called? Exception!
}
```

Just for those do not understand Java, the above code receives something can can be provided a function that takes one parameter, and it supposed to grape this parameter as the final result.

This is not like `callCC`: there is no control flow alternation. Only the inner function's parameter is concerned.

I think the equivalent type signature in *Haskell* should be

```
getFromDoubleAccepter :: (forall b. (a -> b) -> b) -> a
```

So, if someone can gives you a function `(a -> b) -> b` for a type of your choice, he MUST already have an `a` in hand. So your job is to give them a "callback", and than keep whatever they sends you in mind, once they returned to you, return **that** value to your caller.

But I have no idea how to implement this. There are several possible solutions I can think of. Although I don't know how each of them would work, I can rate and order them by prospected difficulties:

- `Cont` or `ContT` monad. This I consider to be easiest.
- `RWS` monad or similar.
- Any other monads. *Pure* monads like `Maybe` I consider harder.
- Use only standard *pure* functional features like lazy evaluation, pattern-matching, the fixed point contaminator, etc. This I consider the hardest (or even impossible).

I would like to see answers using any of the above techniques (and prefer harder ways).

**Note:** There should not be any modification of the type signature, and the solution should do the same thing that the *Java* code does.

**UPDATE**

Once I seen somebody commented out `getFromDoubleAccepter f = f id` I realize that I have made something wrong. Basically I use `forall` just to make the game easier but it looks like this twist makes it too easy. Actually, the above type signature **forces** the caller to pass back whatever we gave them, so if we choose `a` as `b` then that implementation gives the same expected result, but it is just... not expected.

Actually what came up to my mind is a type signature like:

```
getFromDoubleAccepter :: ((a -> ()) -> ()) -> a
```

And this time it is harder.

Another comment writer asks for reasoning. Let's look at a similar function

```
getFunctionFromAccepter :: (((a -> b) -> b) -> b) -> a -> b
```

This one have an naive solution:

```
getFunctionFromAccepter f = \a -> f $ \x -> x a
```

But in the following test code it fails on the third:

```
exeMain = do
    print $ getFunctionFromAccepter (\f -> f (\x -> 10)) "Example 1" -- 10
    print $ getFunctionFromAccepter (\f -> 20) "Example 2" -- 20
    print $ getFunctionFromAccepter (\f -> 10 + f (\x -> 30)) "Example 3" --40, should be 30
```

In the failing case, we pass a function that returns `30`, and we expect to get that function back. However the final result is in turn `40`, so it fails. Are there any way to implement doing **Just** that thing I wanted?

If this can be done in Haskell there are a lot of interesting sequences. For example, tuples (or other "algebraic" types) can be defined as functions as well, since we can say something like `type (a,b) = (a->b->())->()` and implement `fst` and `snd` in term of this. And this, is the way I used in a couple of other languages that do not have native "tuple" support but features "closure".

Comment: I don't fully follow the Java, but I'm pretty certain your type signature is unsatisfiable.  The first parameter is odd: it says how to get any type `b` from an `a`, but I think that's unlikely to be satisfiable.  And then it's meant to produce a type `a` despite having no way to do so (even if the first parameter was slightly less funky there's no way it can output an `a`).  So I think you need to fix your type signature (which you say should not be modified in the answer) before it can be answered.

Comment: Could you please explain what your Java code is supposed to do?

Comment: @NeilBrown, I'm not to the point of understanding the Java either, but that type signature is definitely satisfiable.  Indeed, the *only* total implementation is `getFromDoubleAccepter f = f id`.

Comment: @chris I have updated and add the explaination in the question.

Comment: All those monads you're talking about are implemented *with* "standard pure functional features like lazy evaluation, pattern-matching" etc. So if it's impossible with these "standard features" then it's also impossible with the monads. I also don't see how you can possibly assess the difficulty of any of those approaches if you don't actually know how to solve the problem with any of them.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to move your intuition from Java to Haskell through a hypothetical situation like this. When programming Haskell, whatever problem it is you're trying to solve with this isn't going to come up, at least not in the form you're accustomed to reasoning about with your Java example. I strongly suggest instead of trying to pursue this line of thought, try to write actual programs in Haskell and see what you run into. That's the only real way to build a Haskell intuition.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately your update did not help me understand (since you merely described those parts that where already clear to me). Let me reformulate my question: What is it that you *want* to do with your `getFromDoubleAccepter` function?

Comment: @chris Please refer to my update. More examples has been given.

Comment: `type (a,b) = (a->b->())->()` that is not even close to being true.  Haskell is **pure**.  The correct encoding whould be `forall r. (a -> b -> r) -> r`.  You have the same problem with `getFromDoubleAccepter :: ((a -> ()) -> ()) -> a` which is uninhabited in the total fragment of the language.

Comment: @PhilipJF If you can do `forall r. (a -> b -> r) -> r` you can do `(a->b->())->()` since the later is just a special case of the former. BTW, In my mind, `(forall b. (a -> b) -> b) -> a` is easier than `((a -> ()) -> ()) -> a` and the later is easier than `forall r.((a -> r) -> r) -> a`, am I right?

Comment: @PhilipJF In "Advantures in Classical-Land" by Dan Piponi (The Monad.Reader Issue 6), the author use similar type signatures (he uses `Integer` rather than `()` but that seems not much difference.

Comment: @EarthEngine it is a special case, hence it is not isomorphic.  The type `(forall b. (a -> b) -> b) -> a` is isomorphic to `a` because the quantification is not in prenex position (although proving it is really an isomorphism turns out to be semi-advanced).  The type `((a -> ()) -> ()) -> a` would say `((a -> True) -> True) -> a)` but since `const ()` has type `((a -> () -> ())` (the first part is a tautology)  this is the same as the type `forall a. a` which is uninhabited.

Comment: although this might be inhabited at a specific type (exactly when that specific type is inhabited).  The type `forall a. ((a -> Void) -> Void) -> a` is  not inhabited in intuitionistic settings (Haskell) but is in classical ones.

Comment: @PhilipJF I think you are wrong about `const ()`. That one is a tautology but it is not the same as `((a->())->())`, and I cannot see the relation between them. Also if you have a look at a fixed point combinator it has type signature `(a -> a) -> a` and it is similar to your "uninhabited" types. So since actual programming is not consistent in the logic point of view, "uninhabited" should not prevent you from thinking of their implementation.

Comment: @EarthEngine: what's the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Based upon the language in your update, it seems like you're just trying to shoehorn a Java pattern into Haskell with arbitrary restrictions as some sort of code challenge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of `accept` is `void accept(T)` so the equivalent Haskell type is `t -> IO ()` (since every function in Java is essentially `IO`). Thus `getFromDoubleAccepted` can be directly translated as

```
import Data.IORef

type Accepter t = t -> IO ()

getFromDoubleAccepter :: Accepter (Accepter a) -> IO a
getFromDoubleAccepter acc = do
    l <- newIORef $ error "Not called"
    acc $ writeIORef l
    readIORef l
```

If you want an idiomatic, non-IO solution in Haskell, you need to be more specific about what your actual end goal is besides trying to imitate some Java-pattern.

EDIT: regarding the update

```
getFromDoubleAccepter :: ((a -> ()) -> ()) -> a
```

I'm sorry, but this signature is in no way equal to the Java version. What you are saying is that for any `a`, given a function that takes a function that takes an `a` but doesn't return anything *or do any kind of side effects*, you want to somehow conjure up a value of type `a`. The only implementation that satisfies the given signature is essentially:

```
getFromDoubleAccepter :: ((a -> ()) -> ()) -> a
getFromDoubleAccepter f = getFromDoubleAccepter f
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer and good translation from Java. that uses `IO` but it is still have to modify the given interface.

Answer (score 7):

First, I'll transliterate as much as I can.  I'm going to lift these computations to a monad because `accept` returns `void` (read `()` in Haskell-land), which is useless unless there is some effect.

```
type Accepter m t = t -> m ()

getFromDoubleAccepter :: (MonadSomething m) => Accepter m (Accepter m t) -> m t
getFromDoubleAccepter acc = do
    l <- {- new mutable list -}
    acc $ \t -> add l t
    return (head l)
```

Of course, we can't make a mutable list like that, so we'll have to use some intuitive sparks here.  When an action just adds an element to some accumulator, I think of the [`Writer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html) monad.  So maybe that line should be:

```
    acc $ \t -> tell [t]
```

Since you are simply returning the head of the list at the end, which doesn't have any effects, I think the signature should become:

```
getFromDoubleAccepter :: Accepter M (Accepter M t) -> t
```

where `M` is an appropriate monad.  It needs to be able to write `[t]`s, so that gives us:

```
type M t = Writer [t]

getFromDoubleAccepter :: Accepter (M t) (Accepter (M t) t) -> t
```

And now the type of this function informs us how to write the rest of it:

```
getFromDoubleAccepter acc = 
    head . execWriter . acc $ \t -> tell [t]
```

We can check that it does something...

```
ghci> getFromDoubleAccepter $ \acc -> acc 42
42
```

So that seems right, I guess.  I'm still a bit unclear on what this code is supposed to mean.

The explicit `M t` in the type signature is a bit aesthetically bothersome to me.  If I knew what problem I was solving I would look at that carefully.  If you mean that the argument can be a sequence of commands, but otherwise has no computational features available, then you could specialize the type signature to:

```
getFromDoubleAccepter :: (forall m. (Monad m) => Accepter m (Accepter m t)) -> t
```

which still works with our example.  Of course, this is all a bit silly. Consider

```
   forall m. (Monad m) => Accepter m (Accepter m t))
=  forall m. (Monad m) => (t -> m ()) -> m ()
```

The only thing a function with this type can do is call its argument with various `t`s in order and then return `()`.  The information in such a function is completely characterized[1] by those `t`s, so we could just as easily have used

```
getFromDoubleAccepter :: [t] -> t
getFromDoubleAccepter = head
```

---

[1] As long as I'm going on about nothing, I might as well say that that is not quite accurate in the face of infinity.  The computation

```
crazy :: Integer -> Accepter m (Accepter m Integer)
crazy n acc = crazy (n+1) >> acc n
```

can be used to form the infinite sequence

```
... >> acc 3 >> acc 2 >> acc 1 >> acc 0
```

which has no first element.  If we tried to interpret this as a list, we would get an infinite loop when trying to find the first element.  However this computation has more information than an infinite loop -- if instead of a list, we used the [`Last` monoid](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Monoid.html#t%3ALast) to interpret it, we would be able to extract `0` off the end.  So really

```
forall m. (Monad m) => Accepter m (Accepter m t)
```

is isomorphic to something slightly more general than a list; specifically a free monoid.

Comment: +1 for a lot of information for me to learn about. However I am still waiting for better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above answers, I finally concluded that in Haskell we can do some different things than other languages.

Actually, the motivation of this post is to translate the famous "[single axiom classical logic reduction system](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Reduction_in_the_number_of_the_Primitive_Propositions_of_Logic)". I have implemented this in some other languages. It should be no problem to implement the

```
Axiom: (a|(b|c)) | ((d|(d|d)) | ((e|b) | ((a|e) | (a|e))))
```

However, since the reduction rule looks like

```
Rule: a|(b|c), a |-- c
```

It is necessary to extract the inner parameter as the final result. In other languages, this is done by using side-effects like mutable slots. However, in Haskell we do not have mutable slots and involving `IO` will be ugly so I keep looking for solutions.

In the first glance (as show in my question), the `getFromDoubleAccepter f = f id` seems nonsense, but I realise that it actually work in this case! For example:

```
rule :: (forall r.a -> (b -> c -> r) -> r) -> a -> c
rule abc a = abc a $ flip const
```

The trick is still the same: since the existential qualification hides `r` from the caller, and it is up to the callee to pick up a type for it, we can specify `c` to be `r`, so we simply apply the given function to get the result. On the other hand, the given function has to use our input to produce the final answer, so it effectively limiting the implementation to what we exactally want!

Putting them together, let's see what we can do with it:

```
newtype I r a b = I { runI :: a -> b -> r }

rule :: (forall r. I r a (I r b c)) -> a -> c
rule (I abc) a = abc a (I (\b c -> c))

axiom :: I r0 (I r1 a (I r2 b c)) 
          (I r0 (I r3 d (I r3 d d)) 
                (I r4 (I r2 e b) (I r4 (I r1 a e) (I r1 a e))))
axiom = let 
        a1 (I eb) e = I $ \b c -> eb e b
        a2 =  I $ \d (I dd) -> dd d d
        a3 (I abc) eb = I $ \a e -> abc a (a1 eb e)
        a4 abc = I $ \eb aeae -> runI a2 (a3 abc eb) aeae
    in I $ \abc (I dddebaeae) -> dddebaeae a2 (a4 abc)
```

Here I use a naming convention to trace the type signatures: a variable name is combinded by the "effective" type varialbes (means it is not result type - all `r*` type variable).

I wouldn't repeat the prove represented in the sited essay, but I want to show something. In the above definition of `axiom` we use some let bindings variables to construct the result. Not surprisingly, those variables themselves can be extracted by using `rule` and `axiom`. let's see how:

```
--Equal to a4
t4 :: I r0 a (I r1 b c) -> I r2 (I r1 d b) (I r2 (I r0 a d) (I r0 a d))
t4 abc = rule axiom abc

--Equal to a3
t3 :: I r0 a (I r1 b c) -> I r1 d b -> I r0 a d
t3 abc eb = rule (t4 abc) eb

--Equal to a2
t2 :: I r a (I r a a)
t2 = rule (t3 axiom (t3 (t4 axiom) axiom)) axiom

--Equal to a1
t1 :: I r a b -> a -> I r b c
t1 ab a = rule (t3 t2 (t3 (t3 t2 t2) ab)) a
```

One thing left to be proved is that we can use `t1` to `t4` only to prove all tautologies. I feel it is the case but have not yet proved it.

Compare to other languages, the Haskell salutation seems more effective and expressive.